# Error when declaring a vector in a function in C

Tags: c

I simply try to define a vector named `numlist` in the function `createlist` but the errors I get are:

```
expected constant expression
cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
'numlist' : unknown size
'numlist' undeclared identifier
```

its just this line in the function

```
int langd=3;
int numlist[langd];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a c89 compiler, variable length array is a c99 feature.

To fix your program, use a constant:

```
#define LANGD  3

int langd = LANGD;
int numlist[LANGD];
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to say that I need the size of the array from a parameter in the function its in, like: int function(int a){ int numlist[a]; .........}

Comment: @Tensora in that case, use `malloc` function: `int *numlist = malloc(a * sizeof *numlist);`.